# Merging two arrays into a single array, to be plugged into a function

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, numpy

I have a way I would like to approach my problem, however am struggling with the syntax of the problem.

I have a function, lets call it `f(a,b)`.
I also have an `np.array` of complex numbers for a and b. 
Eg, `a = [1+j, 2+j.....]`, and `b = [3+2j, 4+4j....]`.

What I would like to do is combine these two arrays into an array called c, of the form `c = [(1+j,3+2j),(2+j,4+4j)….]`, where the ith value of `c = [(ai,bi)]`.

I feel I should then plug these ith values of c into my function f(a,b) in a loop (hopefully python can convert ith components of array into two arguments), which would then produce an array of the ith values of f.

I feel this method should work, however the main issue I'm having is syntactical. Does anyone know of any inbuilt functions which could merge two arrays in such a way?

First post on this so any replies would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: The `zip` function should be useful. Try `c = list(zip(a, b))`

Comment: `c = np.stack((a,b), axis=1)` can create a (n,2) array, but given your description of `f` I'm not sure it will help.  Sounds like `f`takes 2 positional scalar arguments, `a` and `b`, and does some sort of math returning another number.  Or can it work with a 2d array?  Or even with a tuple?

Comment: I think you need to give an actual demo `f(a,b)`.  It doesn't have to be exactly the one you'll need, but it should behave just the same with respect to inputs (type and size, etc).

Comment: I will be integrating f using scipy.integrate.simpson. I’ve simplified my function a lot here, but ultimately I’m aiming to produce and array of f(a,b) and then an array of b’s , since the b parameter is the integration variable . I believe scipy.integrate.simpson requires an array of f(a,b) and an array of , in this case, b values to be inputted in to it. So now you see why I’m a bit stuck on getting the syntax correct to produce an array of f(a,b) for different values of a and b in a set range.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension:

```
c = [ci for ci in zip(a, b)]
```

zip will return a iterator over tuples containing one element from `a` and `b`.

With more verbosity, this is:

```
c = [(ai, bi) for (ai, bi) in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use zip :

```
c = zip(a, b)

a = ['x', 'y', 'z']
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = zip(a, b)
c[1]
>>> ('y', 2)
```

Edit : added the example